# localhost:4567 url gets redirected to port 80

Tags: localhost, port-forwarding, redirect, vagrant

I am working with vagrant machines, and everything worked fine until I run this command:

```
vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up
```

I expect that if I go into the browser and I type `http://localhost:4567`, I will be taken to my virtual machine, but after pressing ENTER, the URL bar displays `http://localhost`, which I am guessing means that I have been redirected to port 80.

To make sure I didnt make an error, I removed apache from the host, but I still get the same error.

What could be happening here?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this can give some insight:

```
$ curl -v 127.0.0.1:4567   

* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:4567/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 4567 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:4567
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sat, 06 Sep 2014 12:39:11 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
< X-Pingback: http://sonsi.enriquemorenotent.com/xmlrpc.php
< Location: http://127.0.0.1/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Comment: Have you tried to check for which process might be using that port..?  try sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":80"

Comment: I actually wanted you to substitute the port 80 with 4567 or better yet use curl to check out that url from host as in curl -v localhost:4567. it might give you more information

Comment: curl output: http://pastebin.com/XdYqxkv3

Comment: If you ask me, it looks like apache is running. try disabling it and run that url in your browser or curl it again. sudo service apache2 stop

Answer (score 2):

In the end it was the cache of the browser playing tricks on me. I have marked this question to be deleted by mods, as it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Sorry!